# Remove NVIDIA and i cant start up pc

Tags: drivers, nvidia, startup, 19.10

I am a beginer (newbie) working on ubuntu. I was trying to install my graphics (NVIDIA 1050 "mobile"). I ended up running some commands at the end and when I restarted the computer this appeared to me:

- https://gyazo.com/f269fb439bb75b734214d9e9b0b87ab0

After a few seconds, computer entered the ubuntu user login screen and when computer was starting the user, entered an infinite cycle. I pressed the power button and restart the computer. When I turned on the computer it appeared and never left that screen:

- https://gyazo.com/b61e2e1d15b082cdae62ae8e2bf7544f

I need help I don't know what to do, please help me

Answer (score 0):

Your BIOS settings are corrupt. Did you see this?

> now = Sun Jan 1 00:00:26 2017) is in the future

Suggest you go back into your BIOS/Firmware settings, reset them to defaults, reboot, set the correct date and time, then make other adjustments to match your configuration.

How do you go back into your BIOS/Firmware settings? Depends on the model and make of your PC. Check with your manufacturer's support page to see how.

Comment: I just did this, because my computer is HP and has not changed, it remained the same
https://supportvideos.ext.hp.com/detail/video/4306123709001/restoring-the-bios-default-settings

- https://gyazo.com/b61e2e1d15b082cdae62ae8e2bf7544f

Comment: Is the time correct now?

Comment: I'll check again but I think so

Comment: [link](https://gyazo.com/9497a5734d7e692719435420fc87b1a9)  yes